# How do you create drag and select cell functionality in Angular Kendo grid?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Is there any way in Angular Kendo Grid to click on a cell and drag the mouse to other cells. The other cells are then highlighted and selected. This in turn should return the coordinates of the cells selected.

Expected behavior

1. Select and drag

[image: SelectAndDrag]

2. Everything selected

[image: EverythingSelected]

Comment: Have you already tried enabling cell selection and drag selection properties? https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/